# Implementing anti-symmetric function on two index and for more in systematic way

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, code-request, symmetry

In mathematica, I want to impose symmetric and anti-symmetric properties of $S$ and $A$ in general way.

Usually I was working with explicit information

i.e., for anti-symmetric $A$ with two index, I define

```
ATwo[i_,i_]:=0;
ATwo[2,1]=-ATwo[1,2];
ATwo[3,1]=-ATwo[1,3];
ATwo[3,2]=-ATwo[2,3];
```

and so on and for symmetric with two index I do the similar things

For the higher rank (the range of $i$) It is quite cumbersome to do this explicilty. Is there any other ways to imposing these properties easily?

My first trial was using If, for example

```
ATwo[i_, i_] = 0;
ATwo[i_, j_] := If[j >= i, ATwo[i, j], -ATwo[j, i]];
```

but this results give something wrong when I implement ATwo[3,4] and ATwo[4,3]. For example they produce

```
Hold[ATwo[3, 4]]
Hold[-ATwo[4, 3]]
```

(Maybe it is due to recursive definition?)

Is there any good idea to implement symmetirc or antisymmetric on many index, for example $A[i,j,k,l]$ with i,j symmetric and kl anti-symmetric without explicit plugging as in the first my trial?

Comment: I would use `Signature`, `Sort` and `OrderedQ`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must restrict your patterns, otherwise you get a recursion:

With the definitions:

```
ATwo[i_, i_] = 0;
ATwo[i_, j_] /; j < i = -ATwo[j, i];

A[i_, j_, k_, l_] /; j < i = A[j, i, k, l] ;
A[i_, j_, k_, k_] = 0;
A[i_, j_, k_, l_] /; k < l = - A[i, j, l, k];
```

we can make an example for ATwo:

```
n = 3;
Table[ATwo[i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}] // TableForm
```

[image]

And an example for A:

```
n = 2;
Table[A[i, j, k, l], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}, {l, n}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, which can be easily extended to more symmetric and antisymmetric indices, is :

```
ATwo[i_, j_, k_, l_] := Signature[{k, l}]*(Apply[ATwo])[Join[Sort[{i, j}], 
       Sort[{k, l}]]] /;  !OrderedQ[{i, j}] ||  !OrderedQ[{k, l}]; 
ATwo[i_, j_, k_, k_] = 0;
```